# Query works when ran in SNOWFLAKE UI but when ran through a Stored Procedure. It gives Null records. What needs to be done?

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is the SNOWFLAKE QUERY which I want to run through Stored Proc.
[image]

```
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(INTERNET_ADDRESS, 
             '[A-Z0-9\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&''\\*\\+\\/\\=\\?\\^\\_\`\`\\{\\|\\}\\~\\,\\-]+([\\.]?[A-Z0-9\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&''\\*\\+\\/\\=\\?\\^\\_\`\`\\{\\|\\}\\~\\,\\-])*@[A-Z0-9]+([\\.\\-]?[A-Z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Z]{2,})', 1, 1, 'i') 
  AS INTERNET_ADDRESS_STAGE_3
```

The Above query gives the desired results but when I run it through a Stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EDB_DEV.DM_MESSAGE_GEARS.MESSAGE_GEARS_CUSTOMER_HARISH_TEST()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS  
$$
    var start_time=Date.now(); 
    var execution_id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2); 
    var name = 'MESSAGE_GEARS_CUSTOMER_HARISH_TEST'; 
    var qid = '';
    var error_count = 0 ; 
    try {    
        var sql_command1 = `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE EDB_DEV.DM_MESSAGE_GEARS.CUSTOMER_PROCEDURE_STAGING_TEST_BILAL as (
          SELECT
            INTERNET_ADDRESS,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(INTERNET_ADDRESS, 
             '[A-Z0-9\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&''\\*\\+\\/\\=\\?\\^\\_\`\`\\{\\|\\}\\~\\,\\-]+([\\.]?[A-Z0-9\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&''\\*\\+\\/\\=\\?\\^\\_\`\`\\{\\|\\}\\~\\,\\-])*@[A-Z0-9]+([\\.\\-]?[A-Z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Z]{2,})', 1, 1, 'i') 
  AS INTERNET_ADDRESS_STAGE_3
 FROM EDB_DEV.DM_MESSAGE_GEARS.VW_CUSTOMER)
          
          ;`; 
        var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command1} ); 
        var result1 = statement1.execute(); 
        qid = statement1.getQueryId();
        result1.next();

 

        var result_set = `{"source": "Stored Procedure", "name": "` + name + `", "executionID": "` + execution_id + `", "startTime": "`+ start_time +`" , "endTime":"` + Date.now() + `" , "errorCount": `+ error_count + `}`; 
    } catch (err) { 
        error_count +=1; 
        var result_set = `{"source": "Stored Procedure", "name": "` + name + `", "executionID": "` + execution_id + `", "startTime": "`+ start_time +`" , "endTime":"` + Date.now() + `" , "errorCount": `+ error_count + `, "errorMessage": "Failed: Code: ` + err.code + ` State: ` + err.state + `Message: ` + escape(err.message) + `Stack Trace: ` + err.stackTraceTxt + `"}` 
    } 
   return result_set;
$$;
```

I Get Null records. FOR THE INTERNET_ADDRESS_STAGE_3 field (SKIPPED THE EMAIL CLEANSING gave feild where records are coming as null internet_address  base field where the cleansing is done).
[image]

Comment: I've just tested the code you've provided and it works fine - INTERNET_ADDRESS_STAGE_3 is being populated. As the code you've provided is obviously not what you're actually running (as the table in your screenshot has a lot more columns) you might want to update your question with the actual code. Can you also provide sample data and the result you expect to achieve based on that data?